# Enumerar filas en un template que hace uso de for

Tags: python, django, bucle-for, django-templates

Ando manejando una table en html con la etiqueta de django
`for in` y el cuerpo de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
{% for item in obj  %}
<tr>

    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.descripcion}}</td>
    <td>{{item.estado|yesno:"Activo,Inactivo"}}</td>
    <td>{{item.fc|date:"d/m/Y H:i:s"}}</td>
    <td>{{item.fm|date:"d/m/Y H:i:s"}}</td>

</tr>
```

Lo que quiero es que enumere cada registro de 1..* en lugar de utilizar el `id` del objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es algo que haríamos generalmente en Python con el buitin `enumerate`, de hecho podríamos usarlo para implementarlo en la vista. No obstante, Django en los templates proporciona una serie de [variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) en el `for` específicamente para enumerar cada item del mismo:

- **`forloop.counter`**: es el número de la iteración actual, empezando a contar desde 1 (índice base 1):

  > ```
  > 1  aaa  
  > 2  bbb
  > 3  ccc
  > ```
- **`forloop.counter0`**: es el número de la iteración actual, empezando a contar desde 0 (índice base 0):

  > ```
  > 0  aaa  
  > 1  bbb
  > 2  ccc
  > ```
- **`forloop.revcounter`**: es el número de la iteración actual contando desde el final (enumeración invertida) y comenzando en 1 (índice base 1):

  > ```
  > 3  aaa  
  > 2  bbb
  > 1  ccc
  > ```
- **`forloop.revcounter0`**: es el número de la iteración actual contando desde el final (enumeración invertida) y comenzando en 0 (índice base 0):

  > ```
  > 2  aaa  
  > 1  bbb
  > 0  ccc
  > ```

En tu caso es `forloop.counter` lo que buscas, por lo que solo deberías cambiar:

```
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
```

por:

```
<td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
```